Dropdown Menu Goes Beyond Right Side of Screen
I'm trying to create a multi-level dropdown menu using Bootstrap. By default, the dropdowns should align to the right side, but if there's not enough space, they should switch to align to the left.
The problem I'm facing is that the inner dropdown menus sometimes extend beyond the right side of the screen, especially when there's not enough space.
Here's the relevant code:
HTML and CSS:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-item.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $dropdownMenu = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
    var rect = $dropdownMenu[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    if (rect.right > window.innerWidth) {
      $dropdownMenu.addClass('dropdown-menu-end');
    } else {
      $dropdownMenu.removeClass('dropdown-menu-end');
    }
  });
});
<style>body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.switch-role-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.switch-role {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.welcome-message {
  color: blue;
  text-align: right;
}

.logout-button {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: palevioletred;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -7px;
}

.dropdown-submenu-left {
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu>li:hover>.dropdown-submenu {
  display: block;
}

.nav-item:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-expand-lg {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown-menu-end {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}

</style>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dropdown Menu Alignment</title>
  <style>
    /* Add your CSS here */
  </style>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Menu Item
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item »</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


</body>





I tested your code, and find that you set position: absolute; in .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu. So, the the value of rect.right always related to the class dropdown-menu, and unrelated to dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu, and then it always execute the command $dropdownMenu.removeClass('dropdown-menu-end'); Maybe you can try to use Popper.js to position the dropdown menus, or you can just try to align all the inner dropdown to the left by setting left: -100%;.

You need to override .dropdown-menu[data-bs-popper] class css from left: 0; to right:0; as below:
.dropdown-menu[data-bs-popper] {
  right: 0;
}


Your js code of rect.right do not include the dropdown-submenu element. So, you can try this code as below, to calculate the right boundary of the dropdown-submenu element and add or remove the class dropdown-menu-end:
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(function (dropdownMenu) {
        dropdownMenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            var subdropdownMenu = this.querySelector('.dropdown-submenu li:first-child');
            var $dropdownMenu1 = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');

            if (subdropdownMenu) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var rect = subdropdownMenu.getBoundingClientRect();
                    // console.log('subdropdownMenu rect.right:', rect.right);
                    // console.log('window.innerWidth:', window.innerWidth);

                    if (rect.right > window.innerWidth) {
                        $dropdownMenu1.addClass('dropdown-menu-end');
                        // console.log('Added dropdown-menu-end class');
                    } else {
                        $dropdownMenu1.removeClass('dropdown-menu-end');
                        // console.log('Removed dropdown-menu-end class');
                    }
                }, 50); // Wait for 50 milliseconds before executing, ensuring that the elements have been fully rendered.
            } else {
                // console.log('Submenu Item 1 not found.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Then change the css class .dropdown-menu-end as below:
.dropdown-menu-end { 
    right: 100% !important; 
    left: auto !important;
}

Before:
1
2
After:
1
2
